# What does this notation mean: $[\mathbf{R}]_\times$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

In a paper I'm reading I've come accross this notation several times now and can't figure out what it's supposed to represent. Sometimes it is applied to just one term or a product of terms [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPFYr.png) and sometimes it seems to be applied to a list of arguments [like the occurrence in this matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSsQT.png).

Can anyone help me understand the meaning of this notation?

Comment: @MishaLavrov This is the paper: https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:827236/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: Looks like p.10 says "$[\boldsymbol{a}]_\times$ is the skew-symmetric matrix representation of the vector cross product" which is a more concise and less helpful version of the answer you've already received. But given that the paper has a section for symbols where they define things like *transpose* I'm annoyed that it's not included there.

Comment: Oh and Appendix A spells it out, except that due to an unfortunate typesetting failure it defines $[\boldsymbol{a}]_x$ instead.

Comment: I usually write it as $ [ {\bf r} \times ]$ to indicage that the vector $\bf r$ is transformed into the matrix for the cross product operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $V=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$.

$[V]_{\times}$ denotes the antisymmetrical matrix, associated with the linear operation "taking the cross product with $V$", i.e.,

$$[V]_{\times}X:=V \times X=\begin{pmatrix} -cy+bz\\ \ \  \ cx-az\\-bx+ay \end{pmatrix},$$

which means that 
$$[V]_{\times}=\begin{pmatrix}\ \ \ 0&-c& \ \ \ b\\ \ \ \ c& \ \ \ 0&-a\\-b& \ \ \ a& \ \ \ 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

(this notation is described in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)).

**Remarks:**

1) Very often $V$ is assumed to be unitary ($a^2+b^2+c^2=1$).

2) Here is a very interesting paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0788v1.pdf) where this notation is used with many of its properties grouped in its Appendix A.

3) This notation doesn't look very old ; maybe one should post the question of its origin (robotics ?) on the "history of mathematics" section of SE.

**Edit:**

4) I have had a glance at the source paper you have indicated after I wrote my answer.

In the block-defined matrix, $\hat R^n_{b,k}f_k^b$ has to be a vector. There are two ways to consider this notation:

- a) either as a single matrix  $\hat R^n_{b,k}$ or  $\left(\hat R^n_{b}\right)_k$applied to a vector $f_k^b$, yielding a vector.
- b) or (much less likely) a linear combination of matrices applied to vectors, with a hidden summation sign according to Einstein notation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), $\sum_{b=1}^m \hat R^n_{b,k}f_k^b$ where the summation is on the index that is present once in a lower, once in a upper position, here index $b$.

5) See also the recent document (https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/Cross.pdf) and the older one  (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.825.1726&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (1989)

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to be what the notation means. However I'm still a little unclear what the computation taking place in the matrix in my [second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSsQT.png) is. My first thought would be that the vectors are being multiplied and then the anti-symmetrical matrix is taken, but with the comma I'm not so sure. Is it possible this is just a notational error?

Comment: Ah yes of course, apologies, I was pretty tired when I wrote that comment and it didn't occur to me that the comma was within the subscript. Of course R is a matrix being applied to the vector f, yielding a vector result from which the anti-symmetric matrix is taken.