# Find subspaces Ker(f) and Im(f) where $f$ is defined thus:$f(x)=a \times (x \times b)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given map $$f(x)=a \times  (x \times b)$$

($\times$ is cross product)

find subspaces $\ker(f)$ and $\operatorname{im}(f)$.

My work.

$Ker(f)={a\in V_1|f(a)=\theta_2}$

$Im(f)={f(a)}\in V_2|a\in V_1$

For $Ker(f)$

$f(x)=a$ x ($x $ x $b$) = $\theta_2$

from definition of cross product this means that $x$ x $b$ vector must be colinear with $a$

$x$ x $b$ = $\alpha a$ how from this find $x$?

and for $Im(f)$ I tried but couldn't do anything.

Can we write that $Imf$ = $x(a*c)-b(a*x)$?

And for $Kerf$ can we write that it equals {$x(a*c)-b(a*x)=0$|$x$$\in V_1$}

Comment: I have taken the liberty to suppress tags "general topology", "real analysis", etc. : your question deals with pure linear algebra.

Comment: You could take advantage of the double cross product formula $\mathbf {a} \times (\mathbf {b} \times \mathbf {c} )=\mathbf {b} (\mathbf {a} \cdot \mathbf {c} )-\mathbf {c} (\mathbf {a} \cdot \mathbf {b} ).$

Comment: @JeanMarie I edited my question.

Comment: Another track: the skew symmetric matrix associated with cross product by some fixed vector (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3112576))

Comment: "Can we write that Imf = x(a∗c)−b(a∗x)?". No, not like this, because Im f is a set, therefore necessitates description by curly brackets... But even with those, it is not a correct answer.

Comment: Little remark: you can write $f(x)=- a \times (b \times x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that $a,b$ are nonzero, independent and such that the dot product $s:=a \cdot b \ne 0$.

Let us first write $f$ in a slightly different way, using linearity/antilinearity of cross-product:

$$f(x)=- a \times (b \times x)$$

Using the double cross-product formula, we can give a different form to $f$:

$$f(x)=- b (a \cdot x)+x \underbrace{(a \cdot b)}_s \tag{1}$$

$$f(x)= sx - b(a \cdot x) \tag{2}$$

Using matrix notations, (2) can be written:

$$f(x)=s\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}- \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \tag{3}$$

$$f(x)=\left(\underbrace{sI_3- \begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1&a_2&a_3\end{pmatrix}}_F\right)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \tag{4}$$

where $F=sI_3-BA^T$ is the matrix of $f$.

As $f(b)=sb-b(a \cdot b)=sb-sb=0$, we deduce that $b \in \operatorname{Ker} f$, implying that $\dim \operatorname{Ker} f \ge 1$.

Besides, dealing now with $\operatorname{Im}f$, consider **any** vector $c$ orthogonal to $a$ ; we have, using (2):

$$c \in a^{\perp} \ \implies \ f(c)=sc  \ \implies \ c \in \operatorname{Im}f, \tag{4}$$

where $a^{\perp}$ denotes the plane orthogonal to $a$.

Translating property (4) in terms of sets:

$$a^{\perp} \ \subset \ \operatorname{Im}f \tag{5}$$

As dim$(a^{\perp})=2$, we deduce that dim $\operatorname{Im}f \ge 2$.

As the sum of dim $\operatorname{Ker} f \ge 1$ and dim $\operatorname{Im}f \ge 2$ must be equal to $3$ (rank-nullity theorem), we can conclude that the kernel is one-dimensional, the image is 2 dimensional and that:

$$\operatorname{Ker} f = Span(b) \ \ \ , \ \ \ \operatorname{Im} f = a^{\perp}$$

Geometrical interpretation: If (WLOG) we assume that $s=a \cdot b=1$ and $\|a\|=1$, $f$ appears as the oblique projection onto plane $\operatorname{Im}f=a^{\perp}$ in the direction of vector $b$.

Comment: Thank you for very detail answer just one question.Can you please explain how from  this "implying that $Imf$ contains the plane $a⊥$ orthogonal to $a$." you decided that $Imf$ $\geq$ 2?Sorry if it is silly question.

Comment: Not a silly question. Explanation: **Implication** of properties "$c$ orthogonal to $a" \ \implies c \in Im(f)$ gives **inclusion** of corresponding sets : plane $a^{\perp} \subseteq Im(f)$.

Comment: Yes but why not write dim$Imf \geq 1$ but it is $\geq 2$?

Comment: $a^{\perp}$ is the **plane** orthogonal to $a$, therefore has dimension 2. As a consequence, Im$(f)$, which contains a subspace with dimension 2, has dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: now it clicks thank you very much!.