# Vector Identities proof question, using lagrange's formula

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

How to proof:
$$(\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) \cdot (\vec{C} \times \vec{D}) = (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{C})(\vec{B} \cdot \vec{D})-(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{D} )(\vec{B} \cdot \vec{C}) \space\space\space\space (1)$$
And,
$$\vec{A} \times [\vec{B}\times (\vec{C} \times \vec{D} )] = \vec{B}[\vec{A} \cdot (\vec{C} \times \vec{D})]-(\vec{A}\cdot \vec{B})(\vec{C} \times \vec{D}) \space\space\space (2)$$

The part of the book was talking about using these formulae:
$$\vec{A}\times(\vec{B} \times \vec{C}) = \vec{B}(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{C}) - \vec{C}(\vec{A}\cdot \vec{B})$$
And,
$$\vec{A}\cdot(\vec{B} \times \vec{C}) $$ is associative.

My attempt:
I can't get started on (1); so I tried (2):
For the part $$\vec{B}\times (\vec{C} \times \vec{D}  ) = \vec{C}(\vec{B} \cdot \vec{D}) - \vec{D}(\vec{B} \cdot \vec{C})$$
But I am not sure what to do after that.

Comment: The second question is easy. You can simply replace the cross product between $C$ and $D$ by a new vector $E$ and apply one of the standard formulas.

Comment: Ah, I see now the approach; thanks @M.Wind 
For (1) I assume I let E = A cross B and apply the identitiy formulas as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of the first formula.

Here is a slightly longer approach, using a technique whose interest is to be usable in intricate cases and/or when dealing with cross products in computer programs.

The basic remark is that **cross**-product of two vectors $U=(u_1,u_2,u_3)^T$ and $V=(v_1,v_2,v_3)^T$ can be given the matrix-vector form :

$$\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&-u_3&\ \ u_2\\ \ \ u_3&0&-u_1\\-u_2& \ \ u_1&0}}_{\stackrel{\times}{U}}\underbrace{\pmatrix{v_1\\v_2\\v_3}}_{V}\tag{1}$$

Or, in a condensed way :

$$\stackrel{\times}{U}V=U \times V\tag{2}$$

Please note that $U$ is antisymmetric, i.e.,

$$(\stackrel{\times}{U})^T=-\stackrel{\times}{U}\tag{3}$$

As an exercise, we can check the following identity that will be used at the end:

$$\stackrel{\times}{U}\stackrel{\times}{V}=VU^T-U^TV I_3  \tag{4}$$

either by making a componentwise calculation, or by remarking that, if the LHS and RHS of (*) are applied to a vector $X$, we plainly find back the classical double cross-product formula.

Please note the difference between $U^TV$, a real number (the **dot**-product of $U$ and $V$) and $VU^T$, a matrix.

Now, using the notations above, your first formula can be written under the form :

$$(\stackrel{\times}{A}B)^T(\stackrel{\times}{C}D)\stackrel{?}{=}\underbrace{(A^TC)}_{\text{real number}}B^TD-B^TCA^TD$$

$$B^T(\stackrel{\times}{A})^T\stackrel{\times}{C}D\stackrel{?}{=}B^T(A^TC)D-B^TCA^TD$$

$$B^T(-\stackrel{\times}{A}\stackrel{\times}{C})D\stackrel{?}{=}B^T(A^TCI_3-CA^T)D$$

which is true, being a consequence of identity (4).

See a similar computation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4250884/305862).

Comment: This is a neat and an interesting approach! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using M. Wind hint, I was able to solve (2).
And, using similar way, here is the solution to (1):

Let $$\vec{E} = \vec{C} \times\vec{D} $$
Then, $$(\vec{A} \times \vec{B} )\cdot \vec{E}=\vec{E}\cdot (\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) = \vec{A} \cdot (\vec{B} \times \vec{E})=\vec{A}\cdot(\vec{B}\times(\vec{C}\times\vec{D}))$$
$$=\vec{A}\cdot((\vec{C}(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{D})-\vec{D}(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{C}))$$
$$=(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{C})(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{D})-(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{D})(\vec{B}\cdot\vec{C})$$