# What is $W$ when $W\times X = X'$ for every $X\in \{T, N, B\}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, frenet-frame

($\times$ denotes the usual cross product)

Let $\alpha: I \to R^3$ be a smooth regular curve with non-zero curvature, parametrized by arc length. Given there exists $W: I \to R^3$ such that $W\times X = X'$ for every $X\in \{T, N, B\}$, where that last set is the Frenet-Serret frame of $\alpha$, we are asked to determine W. (probably in terms of the basis {T, N, B}).

I was able to conclude, using Frenet-Serret formulas that the $N$ component is $0$ since $W\times T = T' = kN$ therefore since $k\neq 0$, $N$ is orthogonal to $W$. So $W = aT + bB$ for some functions $a,b$. Now i'm stuck. Any hint?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas

Comment: @Max Yes i am aware of those formulas and used them, but i don't know how to apply them here to proceed further.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2248459/2633 aka https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Cross_product

Comment: Now compare the two (in the N, T, B basis).

Comment: You used $W \times T = T' = \kappa N$, but didn't finish saying how a,b were related to $\kappa$. After that use $W \times B = B' = -\tau N$.